# Split dataframe column into 2 based on row content in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidycensus

I'm using tidy census and I have 2 variables for each census tract which makes my data frame look like this:

| GEOID | tract | variable | estimate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24005400100 | Tract 4001 | white_pop | 3436 |
| 24005400100 | Tract 4001 | black_pop | 98 |

but I want my variables as separate columns with their estimate as the row content:

| GEOID | tract | white_pop | black_pop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24005400100 | Tract 4001 | 3436 | 98 |

This is my code to load in the data:

```
BA_2009_data = get_acs(geography = "tract", 
                  state = "MD",
                  county = "Baltimore County",
                  variables = c(white_pop = "B02008_001", black_pop = "B02009_001"),
                  year = 2009)
```

I'm fairly new to R, so I am not sure how to work with this.

Comment: Using `data.table` - `dcast(setDT(df), GEOID + tract~variable, value.var = 'estimate')` Or `tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = variable, values_from = estimate)`

Comment: Use the argument `output = "wide"` in `get_acs()` - this is all you have to do!